# Prestashop multiple cart created in short time interval

Tags: prestashop

The last days my store show more than hundred abandoned cart create by non registered customer.

the logs show that the activity is coming from a specific IP: 157.56.176.228.

Googling the IP show that it's some sort of Microsoft service.
Is there away to block it?

Comment: You can try to override the `CartController` and prevent `postProcess` from adding product to cart based on ip adresses.

Comment: I did an override for the function : **processChangeProductInCart** as below:

`...
if (!$this->errors && $mode == 'add'
 **&& (Tools::getValue("token") == Tools::getToken(false)) 
&& !preg_match('/robot|bot|slurp|spider|crawler|curl|^$/i',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])**) { ...}`

Comment: Ok, let us know if it works and post it as an answer to your own question ;)

Comment: Again asking and answering myself,
the override work fine.